# Rune names in Old Norse

Tags: ligature, old-norse

I understand that the runes of the younger futhark alphabet had names such as hagall and bjarkan, I also understand that these rune names had meanings as other words in old norse, such as hail and birch, I also understand that these runes were sometimes ligatured together to form bindrunes.  Were rune names ever spelled out with other runes in old norse or were the runes themselves considered the words of their rune names as D and S are considered words? When these runes were joined as ligatures as bindrunes, I understand that these bindrunes are considered one individual glyph, was this glyph considered one rune or one word in old Norse or did these bindrunes have any names themselves or were they read as two separate runes even though they are called one glyph. The Bluetooth logo is a bindrune of hagall and bjarkan, the initials of Harald Bluetooth, when the two are separated they are read as two initials “hagall” and “bjarkan”.

[image]

When they are joined are they still read separately or is this glyph read as hagallbjarkan as one word in old norse, when are the words ha fall and bjarkan used to write the initials and are the runes alone used?

Comment: This seems to be about Old Norse rather than English.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about English, but rather Old Norse.

Comment: This question is about a language that contributed significantly to English.

Comment: I am not going to vote to close, but I suggest that you look at [Linguistics SE](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/) and decide if you would get a better answer there; I think you would.